# -accountId cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, arraylist, field

I can't figure out what's the problem with my method, I have an ArrayList named accounts which I'm trying to implement into this other class' method. I'm getting this errormessage: "Multiple markers at this line -accountId cannot be resolved or is not a field -accountId cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Why doesn't it work?

```
public boolean deposit(long pNr, int accountId, double amount){

        for(int i = 0; i < customerlist.size(); i++)
        {
            if(this.pNr == pNr)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < accounts.size(); j++)
                {
                    if(accountId == accounts.accountId)//problem seem to be here
                    {
                        balance = balance + amount;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accounts` seems to be a List, so you should try to access the field of an item of this List instead of accessing the item of the List itself.

```
if(accountId == accounts.get(j).accountId)
{
    balance = balance + amount;
}
```

And you should iterate over your list with an `Iterator` or a foreach - then you don't have to access every item manually.

I've made some changes, so you have to adapt the following piece to fit in your code:

```
public boolean deposit(long pNr, int accountId, double amount){
    for(Customer customer : customerlist)
    {
        if(pNr == customer.getPNr())
        {
            for(SavingsAccount account : accounts)
            {
                if(accountId == account.getAccountId())
                {
                    balance += amount;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you want to access private fields of other objects, you have to use a getter (like `getAccountId()` or `getPNr()`) - these are methods which just return "their" private field.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. Maybe my thinking is wrong.

1. I have a class Customer, a class SavingsAccount and a class BankLogic. The deposit need to fit the Customers pNr and the SavingsAccounts accountId. In this method from BankLogic.

2. Isn't that how you do when you want to compare a private variable from another class?

Comment: @MiaRaunegger by clicking on the sign below the down vote button next to the answer: "click to set this answer as your accepted answer; click again to toggle"

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
//for lists
if(accountId == accounts.get(j).accountId)
//for arrays
if(accountId == accounts[j].accountId)
```

On the problem line.

Your current code is trying to get the accountId of the list not of the listitem. Using get() (or [] if it's an array) will select the item in the list of that index.

Answer (score 0):

Using my magic crystal ball, I'm going to say that `accounts` is of type `List<Account>`. You need to get the account at position `j`.

**Example**

```
if(accountId == accounts.get(j).accountId) {
}
```

***NOTE***: You shouldn't be exposing `accountId`. This should be retrieved via an accessor method, so it should read something like:

```
if(accountId == accounts.get(j).getAccountId()) {
}
```